# Reporting Install Date +90days

Tags: reporting

I am trying to create a report based on the 'Customer Installation Completed Date'plus 90 days on the Opportunity AND 'Was this a Referral?' Checkbox on the Account is True

I tried to create a formula field to populate this (90+ date of completion) using the following syntax-

IF( Was_this_a_Referral__c = TRUE, NULL, Opportunity__r.Customer_Installation_Completed_Date__c +90)

I did this so this 'Install +90 days' field is available to report on.

1)I am not sure if I am taking the correct route to report on this
2)Not sure if the formula I created is correct
3) If 1 &2 are correct then currently that new formula field is not populating any dates.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of If Function is If(Logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)

Assuming 'Was_this_a_Referral__c' as field name for checkbox, you only need to have formula as 

If( Was_this_a_Referral__c , null , (Date1+90) ). You can check the formula using syntax check in formula builder.  Date1 is just mentioned as a sample date here, you can replace with your actual date.

Once this formula field shows correct data, you can use in Reports.  
 You can also use fields from related objects using formula builder.
In case formula is wrong, you will get the exact error message.

You can share the error message if you get any.

Comment: I attempted to use formula 
If( Was_this_a_Referral__c , null , ( Opportunity__r.Customer_Installation_Completed_Date__c +90) )

It did not query the +90 day date in the field. No errors with the formula either. 

The 'Was this a Referral ' field is a checkbox (field under Account) and is a requirement then only should it calculate the +90 days after the 'Customer Installation Completed Date' (under Opportunity related to account) and fill it in the ' Install Completed +90 day' Field under Account

Comment: Is this not populating in my Accounts field because we are pulling from Opportunities and because it is a one to many and the field wouldnt know which to populate of the many opportunities it could have?